# Loop connect multiple routers and executing commands paramiko SSH

Tags: python, loops, command, paramiko, execute

I'm trying to create a script to connect to my routers and execute some commands.

The ip address are stocked in .txt file.

The script does not execute when I have multiple addresses in the file, when I try with only one ip address, it works fine.

Can somebody help please?

Thank you!

Here's my code:

```
import socket
import sys
import paramiko
import time
import subprocess
import platform
iplist = "ip_address.txt"

with open(iplist,'r') as fp:
    ips = fp.readlines()

for ip_address in ips:
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip_address,port=22,username=username,password=password,look_for_keys=False)
    print ("Successfully connected to", ip_address)

    remote_connection = ssh_client.invoke_shell()

#remote_connection.send("system-view" + "\n")
#remote_connection.send("interface GigabitEthernet 0/0/5" + "\n")
#remote_connection.send("shutdow" + "\n")
remote_connection.send("disp ip int brie" + "\n")
time.sleep(5)
output = remote_connection.recv(65535)
output = output.decode("utf-8")
print (output)



remote_connection.send("quit\n")



ssh_client.close
```

Comment: You need to indent even all the code that executes the commands under the `for ip_address in ips`.

Comment: thank you for your reply... it work now !
I just moved the code under the loop !

Comment: You are welcome. Please delete your question.

Comment: Is not préférable to let it for somme one who will have this problem in the future ... ?